# Flex package question

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In which .swc package are the flash.net namespace classes found?

I think it is either Flex.swc or Framework.swc but I'm not sure.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. It belongs to the `playerglobal.swc`. See [About SWC files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=compilers_123_42.html) in Flex  documentation.

Comment: True.  But I'll add that the flash.* classes aren't actually in the playerglobal.swc file.  They are just stubs since the real implementation is native in Flash Player.